# Enable legacy TLS using annotations

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

The default method documented for enabling legacy TLS is using config maps:

https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/tls/#legacy-tls

Is it possible to add this support using ingress annotations?

Comment: Can you post your `ingress`?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it via a [custom configuration snippet](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#configuration-snippet) annotation. For example:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
      ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA;
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: my-service
    servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your code and deployed a new helm release, but it didn't enable tlsv1, tlsv1.1